# Greatest Integer Function $ [x^2] $ : Riemann Integration Question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, riemann-integration

How to show $$ [x^2]  $$ is Riemann Integrable in [0,2] ?

I will explain how I proceeded my doubt is with greatest integer function part, 
after splitting into 3 intervals

$$[0,1],[{1,\sqrt 2 }], [{\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3 }], [{\sqrt 3,2] }$$

In the interval $$[0,1]$$ Supremum of function is 1 and Infimum is 0.

In the interval $$[{1,\sqrt 2 }]$$ Supremum of function is 2 and Infimum is 1.

In the interval $$[{\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3 }]$$ Supremum of function is 3 and Infimum is 2.

Now U(P,f) = $$ 1(1-0)+2(\sqrt 2-1)+ 3(\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2)+4(2-\sqrt 3)                 $$

and L(P,f) = $$ 0(1-0)+1(\sqrt 2-1)+ 2(\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2)+3(2-\sqrt 3)                 $$
and they are different values. Please help.

Comment: What's with the title dude?

Comment: Is the title ok now? Should I delete the question?

Comment: You should add some more context, e.g., what sums you're getting, etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, I have added what I know.

Comment: What about considering semi-open intervals ?

Comment: How? Is there anything wrong in the way I have calculated Upper and Lower Riemann Sums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one is helping with the answer, I figured out an answer after referring through various questions in Riemann Integrability.

Since the function $ [x^2]  $ is discontinuous at $1,\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3  $ in the interval [0,2], 
we partition the interval as follows:

x<sub>0</sub>($=0$), x1 , x2 .... xi, y<sub>0</sub>($=1$), y1 , y2.... yi,z<sub>0</sub> (=$\sqrt 2$),z1 , z2.... zi, k<sub>0</sub> (=$\sqrt 3$),k1 , k2.... ki,m<sub>0</sub>$(=2)$

Now U(P,f)= 0*$\Sigma$x<sub>i</sub> + 1*(y<sub>0</sub>-x<sub>i</sub>) +1*$\Sigma$y<sub>i</sub> + 2*(z<sub>0</sub>-y<sub>i</sub>) + 2*$\Sigma$z<sub>i</sub> +3*(k<sub>0</sub>-z<sub>i</sub>)+ 3*$\Sigma$k<sub>i</sub> + 4*(m<sub>0</sub>-k<sub>i</sub>)

=$0+1*(\sqrt2-1)+2*(\sqrt3-\sqrt2)+3*(2-\sqrt3)+$1*(y<sub>0</sub>-x<sub>i</sub>) +2*(z<sub>0</sub>-y<sub>i</sub>) +3*(k<sub>0</sub>-z<sub>i</sub>) + 4*(m<sub>0</sub>-k<sub>i</sub>)

Take
        $\epsilon$ = 1*(y<sub>0</sub>-x<sub>i</sub>) +2*(z<sub>0</sub>-y<sub>i</sub>) +3*(k<sub>0</sub>-z<sub>i</sub>) + 4*(m<sub>0</sub>-k<sub>i</sub>)

Now L(P,f)= 0*$\Sigma$x<sub>i</sub> + 0*(y<sub>0</sub>-x<sub>i</sub>) +1*$\Sigma$y<sub>i</sub> + 1*(z<sub>0</sub>-y<sub>i</sub>) + 2*$\Sigma$z<sub>i</sub> +2*(k<sub>0</sub>-z<sub>i</sub>)+ 3*$\Sigma$k<sub>i</sub> + 3*(m<sub>0</sub>-k<sub>i</sub>)

=$0+1*(\sqrt2-1)+2*(\sqrt3-\sqrt2)+3*(2-\sqrt3)+$  1*(z<sub>0</sub>-y<sub>i</sub>) +  +2*(k<sub>0</sub>-z<sub>i</sub>)+  3*(m<sub>0</sub>-k<sub>i</sub>)

Now taking U(P,f) - L(P,f) <  $\epsilon$

Hence $ [x^2]  $ is Riemann Integrable in [0,2]

Answer (score 1):

I think the conceptual issue is that you're choosing specific partitions that *don't* have good behavior and using that to argue that the function is not Riemann integrable.

Let me ask you this: would you also think that $x^2$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,2]$ since on $[0,1]$ the max is $1$ and min is $0$ and on $[1, 2]$ the max is $4$ and min is $1$? I would hope not.

The heart of what it means for a function to be Riemann integrable is you get these upper and lower sums to be arbitrarily close to each other *when you choose the right partition.* More often than not, the "right" partition is simply one whose parts are sufficiently small. You can now clearly see why continuity is sufficient for Riemann integrability since continuity guarantees that the difference between the max and min in each part is small when the part is small.

Comment: sufficiently small means? here what should be the partition size or specifically what should be the partitions to prove R-integrability?

Comment: And unlike  $$ x^2 $$ the greatest integer function has the same value in an interval except at the end points, right?

Comment: Sufficiently small means the size of each interval that make up the whole is small. I think you should review your definitions of Riemann integrability and try to get a better understanding of the concepts and come back.